# How to empty a table in SQLITE once a limit is reached?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

lets say I have a table named events. I want to know how I can limit the number of rows in the table.
for example,

**when there are 30 rows present in the table, I want to print all the rows in logging in android studio and then empty the table without deleting its structure.**

EDITED :

I am aware of the command **"DELETE"**. However, I am wondering if there is a mechanism to call this DELETE function only when lets say 30 rows have been filled in the table.

Comment: This is SQL right? So how about `delete` ?

Comment: How to put a condition on the limit? only when it reaches 30 rows, I want to delete. And checking the db every second is a costly operation. @ScaryWombat

Comment: before insert check the count

Answer (score 1):

Create a trigger that checks after each insertion of a new row the number of rows in the table and if this number is >= 30 the table is cleared:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Clear_Table
AFTER INSERT ON tablename
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename) >= 30
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM tablename;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm newbie on sqlite. But if I am in your status, I'll do empty table with following query.

```
DELETE FROM TARGET_TABLE
```

After executing this query, I can insert again without problem.

Comment: I am aware of this command. Please check the problem again.

Comment: @coder Ok, then consider answer of forpas. I checked it works.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your function that inserts in the table.

In your insert method you first need to check number of entries in your table by "count" function if they are more than 30 or whatever count you need run the "delete" command.

there is no predefined command for such requirement.